# How to solve numerically an equation which contains numerical integration?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

```
    F1[x_] := NIntegrate[E^Sin[y x], {y, 0, 1}]
    F2[x_] := Log[x]
    NSolve[F1[x] == F2[x], x]
```

I want to solve the equation, but Mathematica don't solve it. What I should do?

Comment: For one thing, `DSolve` is for solving *differential* equations. For another, an equation with a non-analytical integral is probably too hard for `Solve` and `NSolve`. Try `FindRoot[..., {x, 1}]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be solved via a numerical method called [fixed point iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) reasonably quickly...

```
FixedPoint[F1[#] - F2[#] + # &, 2, 100]
(* result 4.609527035642726` takes about 0.327602 seconds on my machine *)
```

Answer (score 9):

Let's first define `F1` to take only numeric arguments because otherwise `FindRoot` or other functions you might use on it will try to supply some symbolic arguments to it and result in uninteresting messages:

```
Clear[F1]
F1[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[E^Sin[y x], {y, 0, 1}]
```

Now plot the functions to see an expected starting point for solution search:

```
Plot[{F1[x], F2[x]}, {x, -3, 15}]
```

[image: two functions plot]

Now we can see the solution is near `5`, so let's just find the root:

```
FindRoot[F1[x] == F2[x], {x, 5}]
```

> {x -> 4.60952703564273}